# convert tree structure into php array

Tags: php, arrays

i have the tree solution but i want to convert it into array ...

```
 function generatePageTree($datas , $parent = 0)
$tree = '<ul>';
for($i=0, $ni=count($datas); $i < $ni; $i++){
    if($datas[$i]['parent_id'] == $parent){
        $tree .= '<li>';
        $tree .= $datas[$i]['ledger_account_name'];
        $tree .= $this->generatePageTree($datas, $datas[$i]['ledger_account_id']);
        $tree .= '</li>';
    }
}
    $tree .= '</ul>';
return $tree;
}
```

i want this tree structure in form of array.. can any one already done please help....
array format............

```
 array(
      id=>100, parentid=>0, name=>'a', children=>array(
        id=>101, parentid=>100, name=>'a', children=>array(
          id=>102, parentid=>101, name=>'a',
          id=>103, parentid=>101, name=>'a',
        )
      )
    )
```

Comment: so what is your desired array format?

Comment: hey thank you for your help , but i found the answer ...

Comment: Please let me know the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function buildTree(array $elements, $parentId = 0) {
          $branch = array();

          foreach ($elements as $element) {

              if ($element['parent_id'] == $parentId) {
                  $children = $this->buildTree($elements, $element['ledger_account_id']);

                  if ($children) {

                      $element['children'] = $children;

                  }
                  $branch[$element['ledger_account_id']] = $element;
              }
          }

          return $branch;
      }
```