# How do I turn a flat array with no Parent IDs into a tree object? (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, tree

I have a multidimensional array like:

```
Grandfather's name | Father's name | Son's name
JOHN | RAY | TERRENCE
JOHN | TIM | MICHAEL
JOHN | TIM | RYAN
BILL | SAM | HANK
BILL | SAM | WILL
BILL | LEO | DONALD
JACK | ROD | FITZGERALD
JACK | ABE | GEORGE
JACK | ALI | HARRY
```

and I'd like to turn it into a nested JSON object like

```
JOHN
    RAY
        TERRENCE
    TIM
        MICHAEL
        RYAN
```

etc..

Right now, I'm doing a few for loops checking for when the grandfather's name changes, then when the father's name changes. But that is not very futureproof nor reusable. What's a better (more reusable, more efficient, more readable) way to do this? (In a way that is implementable in PHP)

I realize some assumptions are in order. I'm looking for a way to accomplish this for n number of columns without knowing the number of columns in advance. But with the assumption that the hierarchy is ordered in the same order as the columns (so each subsequent column is a deeper set).

Comment: Could you give us a complete array example?

Comment: Added example. Name lengths are immaterial, just used similar lengths for easy formatting...

Comment: What you provided as output is not JSON. Can you provide the *exact* JSON you want as output? The same for the input: that is not a valid PHP array notation. Please provide the correct PHP syntax of your input to avoid misunderstandings.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the rows, and you need a single line of code to generate the array.

```
$rows = array(array('A', 'B', 'C'), array('A', 'B', 'D'), array('A', 'X', 'Y'));
$data = array();

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $data[$row[0]][$row[1]][$row[2]] = 1;
}

echo json_encode($data); // {"A":{"B":{"C":1,"D":1},"X":{"Y":1}}}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but what if I don't know the number of columns in advance? Is there a way to do this that works for an arbitrary number of columns?

Comment: That's a bad structure in the DB to do that. What you want is only 2 columns: id and parent_id. I answered your question as you put it :-) You can check out something similar to what you want here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30205981/convert-tree-structure-into-php-array

Comment: I agree, if I had my way I would have the data in a nested set model (left, right). Unfortunately in this case I don't have control over the data source. In fairness, I did say in the original question: "I'm looking for a way to accomplish this for n number of columns without knowing the number of columns in advance". But if I don't get another answer soon, you will have my green checkmark ;)